# How do you log previewView.bitmap in Android Kotlin (Jetpack Compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-jetpack-compose

I just want to log live bitmap data from the previewScreen, but the documentation for PreviewView.bitmap says:

"If the preview hasn't started yet, the method may return null or an empty Bitmap. Use getPreviewStreamState() to get the PreviewView.StreamState and wait for PreviewView.StreamState.STREAMING to make sure the preview is started."

I'm just not sure how to implement that. Please help!

Here's my composable:
`

```
package com.example.livestreamdemo.screens

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.livestreamdemo.util.Common.REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS

@Composable
fun CameraPreviewScreen() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val cameraProviderNext = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }



    var hasCamPermission by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            })
    }

    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
        onResult = { granted ->
            hasCamPermission = granted.size == 2
        }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        launcher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        )
    }
    if(hasCamPermission) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = { ctx ->
                val previewView = PreviewView(ctx)
                val exec = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx)
                cameraProviderNext.addListener({

                    val cameraProvider = cameraProviderNext.get()
                    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                        .also {
                            it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                        }
                    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                        .build()

                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner,
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview
                    )

                }, exec)
                previewView
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        )
    }
}
```

`

I've tried logging previewView.bitmap but it's returned null so I just need to know how to wait for PreviewView.StreamState.STREAMING somehow. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try to implement it in the back thread?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm having trouble implementing a coroutine from a composable. I'm pretty new to Android. I tried this 
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
...
coroutineScope.launch {
   ...
}
But it gave me an error saying that I could only launch it from a suspend function.